# Auto sync content from one alfresco to other and vice versa

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have two servers with alfresco installed. Now i want to sync the data from one alfresco to the other, automatically on timely basis. So that it becomes complete replica in case of server failure. How can i do that? Any web-scripts or similar resources would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the [built-in Replication Service](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/admintools-replication-config.html)? Or [turn on high-availability clustering](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/ha-intro.html)?

Comment: thanks @Gagravarr will check it.

Comment: Note that both services are Enterprise Edition only. If you use the Community Edition, they are not available.

Comment: @LutzHorn I used alfresco 3.2 community edition. Is there any web scripts  that can do similar or just take backup and let the user download it?